# How can I develop a BlueTooth device that can connect to both Android and iOS devices?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need to create software to connect a Bluetooth device (I can use BLE). I tried [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html) that connects to iPhones successfully. But in this example, one iPhone sends data (Peripheral) and other receive the data (Central), while I need to connect the device to send *and* receive data. I research for several BLE devices and I didn't find anything about how and if the device can do both operations (send and receive).

I also need to know if I can use the same Bluetooth device to connect with iPhone and Android phones, too (I heard about dual mode, or something like that).

So, my questions are:

1. Can I have a Bluetooth device that can send and receive data to/from an iPhone? If yes, what I need (hardware and software[something more then Xcode?])?
2. How do I program a Bluetooth device to use Apple protocols? Do I need a dev kit or something special for Apple?
3. Can I have a Bluetooth device that can be connected by an iPhone and Android (not necessarily at the same time)? Does this require special consideration?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Yes you can. The question is what kind of device are you thinking on? But, you'd have to develop the micro-controllers, etc. The iOS application `LightBlue` is good. I use it to debug. There is a good WWDC Session about it.

2)Bluetooth Low-Energy has a protocol, it has nothing to do with Apple...

3)Android doesn't officially support BLE. It has no framework. Motorola uses a self made framework. Others, I don't know, and that's the case when they have a BLE-chip.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Larme!
So:
1) I'm going to use a  Bluegiga - Evaluation BT111 to construct a device that will send information for the iPhone. When i tryed Peripheral/Central from 1 iPhone to another that workd fine. My question is when i use the Bluegiga - Evaluation BT111, how will that works? Its just send a signal and corebluetooth will get it?
Can u link me the LightBlue app and the WWDC Session?
3) I think a dual mode module can work on both devices, onde time at will be ble and another will be normal bluetooth signal...

Comment: LightBlue: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lightblue/id557428110?mt=8
WWDC: It's the Session #705, name Advanced Core Bluetooth (Go to the iOS Portal to find it).
Before using to the Bluegiga, I suggest you to use LightBlue.

Answer (score 0):

1)You can use the same framework (CoreBluetooth) to put the iPhone in central or peripheral role. For the peripheral role you only need XCode and iOS 6 or higher and a own central (another iPhone, Android Smartphone, a BLE USB Dongle, etc.).

2)There aren't any "Apple protocols", you have to respect the Bluetooth specs.

3) No, a bluetooth device can only be connected to one master at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I think our app LightBlue would be nice to help you out.  I just want to add that we have just added a tutorial that can be found here: http://blog.punchthrough.com/post/46285311872/testing-bluetooth-low-energy-devices

Regarding your question #3, Yes you can have a device that is device-agnostic.  However I recommend developing first for iOS, some of Apple's requirements are more stringent than android (connection interval, for example).

The Samsung Galaxy S3 seems to be the most used BLE capable device.  Motorola has their own BLE stack which is functional but quite flakey at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

1. It all depends on the device that you are aiming to communicate.if it is external accessory,EA Hardware's chip needs to be a complaint of MFI from apple.
2. You have external Accessory Framework which will establish BT connection and finding devices etc etc..